# Magento 404 Error in frontend after upgrading 1.4.1.1 to 1.6.1.0

Tags: magento

I upgrade my magento store 1.4.1.1 to 1.6.1.0 following instruction from [this link](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-from-1-4-version-to-magento-1-5-magento-1-6/). Upgrade was successfully done. My Magento backend is working fine. But while I checking front end I got *404 error*.

I tried various advice in Google. But none of them helps me.

If you have previous experience in this please share.

Edit :-

I think this problem is occurred due to multi store setup.so i share two table structures

```
core_store
```

[image]

```
core_store_group
```

[image]

```
Core_website
```

[image]

Comment: Which 404 page?  http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages (self link describing the various 404 pages Magento could show you, each of which has its own reason for showing up)

Comment: @AlanStorm:thanks for the response i am getting 404 page like second screenshot in your article under the title "Customizing the Store Exception 404 Page".I'm having multi store setup,I guess problem is in this setup.any idea.i share my core_store and core_store_group tables.please check it

Comment: That means there's an exception being throw somewhere in the stack.  What gets added to your PHP error log and/or Magento Exception log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself:-
In "core_store" table some of the stores was disabled.While activate the all stores the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the cache, rebuild catalog url rewrite index, check .htaceess and mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem recently. 
Check to see if any modifications of the root index.php file have been overridden by the upgrade. 
You probably updated the $mageRunCode depending on what url you come to the site on, this will have been replaced by a default index.php file with the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem and i tried all solution above and also from google but its not solve the problem in the end i tried one solution that is in .htaccess file in root directory

```
############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#########
```

i just comment the above line like

```
#RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

and then add this code

```
####
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /magento/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this will fix my problem and then all categories page and products page are opening perfect and no more 404 error or forbidden error comes. just posted it might be its help others